# Can we execute the pro-c file which is compiled on UNIX on Debian 9?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, c

I have a **pro-c** file which is compiled on **UNIX**.

The script logins to **oracle DB** and interacts with DB and update some values there in some tables.

We are migrating from **UNIX** to **Openshift Container Platform** where the containers are **Docker** based. The images are **httpd** based which inturn is **debian:stretch-slim** based.

Can we really run the **UNIX compiled pro-c** file on **httpd** image which is **Debian** based?

When I try to run it, I'm getting `Not found` error though the file is in the same directory.

The name of the file is **flp0200**

I tried executing it using `./flp0200` and `flp0200` . But none of them worked.

Can anyone point me in right direction?

Comment: How do you try to run it? Where (in the filesystem) is the executable? What's the exact error message? Please [edit] your question to add this information - don't reply in a comment.

Comment: I see your edit. Let's try again. How do you try to run it (full and precise command line)? What's the **exact and complete** error message?

Comment: I'm not aware of any error message as terse as `Not found`. Even on AIX. What is the **FULL AND COMPLETE** error message?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to run a program compiled on AIX, on a debian box.

Recompile from source on the target platform.

Comment: Even with the same architecture?

Comment: Correct.  AIX executables do not use the ELF [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats?wprov=sfti1) binary format, for one thing.  Secondly, any program written from a non-AIX system will have system calls defined for libraries the compiler had available to it, not the AIX specific versions of those libraries.
Scripting and interpreted languages are much easier to work with cross-platform.